# Prove by induction that $\sum_{i=1}^{k} a^{k-i} b^{i-1}=\frac{a^{k}-b^{k}}{a-b}$

Tags: solution-verification, induction

Prove by induction that the following is true:
$$ \frac{a^{n}-b^{n}}{a-b}=a^{n-1}+a^{n-2} b+a^{n-3} b^{2}+\cdots+a b^{n-2}+b^{n-1} \quad(a \neq b) $$

---

Induction step:
Assume that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k} a^{k-i} b^{i-1}=\frac{a^{k}-b^{k}}{a-b}$$
is true. It follows that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a^{k-i} b^{i-1}&=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} a^{k-i} b^{i-1}\right) +a^{k-(k+1)} b^{(k+1)-1} \\
&= \frac{a^{k}-b^{k}}{a-b}+a^{-1} b^{k}\\
&=\frac{a^{k}-b^{k}}{a-b}+\frac{b^{k}}{a} \\
&= \frac{a\left(a^{k}-b^{k}\right)+(a-b) b^{k}}{a(a-b)}\\
&\frac{a^{k+1}-b^{k} a+b^{k} a-b^{k+1}}{a(a-b)}\\
&= \frac{a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}}{a(a-b)}
\end{align}$$
and I get this $a$ on the denominator that shouldn't be there. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You should start from this: $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a^{(k+1)-i} b^{i-1}$

Comment: The exponent of $a$ should be $(k+1)-i$ when trying to prove that it’s true for $k+1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So everything in your proof is correct, but you made a mistake in your first line with indexing. What you actually want to show is $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a^{k+1-i}b^{i-1}=\frac{a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}}{a-b}$$ instead of  $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a^{k-i}b^{i-1}=\frac{a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}}{a-b}$$

So if we note this mistake, then your proof is complete if you just multiply by $a$ to everything you wrote in your proof.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} a^{k+1-i} b^{i-1}&=\sum_{i=1}^{k} a^{k+1-i} b^{i-1}+b^k\\
&=a\cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^{k} a^{k-i} b^{i-1}\right)+b^k\\[2mm]
&=a\left(\frac{a^k-b^k}{a-b}\right)+b^k\\[2mm]
&=\frac{a^{k+1}-ab^k+ab^k-b^{k+1}}{a-b}\\[1mm]
&=\frac{a^{k+1}-b^{k+1}}{a-b}
\end{align*}